# How do you find a file in visual studio code workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Fairly new to visual studio code. I know you can:

1. cmd/ctrl+p and search for the file but I want to see a nice layout in the explore like what edit --> find files does.
2. Edit -> Find in files. But not looking for words inside the files. I just want the actual file.

I want to search for foo.cpp and get the results like I do in edit --> find files.

This was a command that I found but it's not even in the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+f",
    "command": "filesExplorer.findInWorkspace",
    "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !inputFocus"
},
```

This kinda works but when I do '.go' I only find 2 files. I know the hugo repo has way more than 2 go files.

[image]

I would like the results for found files to output like this. But this outputs words found in a file not the file itself.

[image]

I guess for now I will just do the good old terminal command.

```sh
fd -t f '.*\.cpp' dir/
```

I think this would probably have to be an extension similar to todo tree if I wanted that output.

Comment: @Julia yes I know I can do that as mentioned in 1. But I would like those results in the explorer bar. Is that possible? Just like you can do edit --> find in files.

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. I don't know how to do that, but if the folder is "uncollapsed" in the file explorer, you can click the file explorer area and start typing.

Comment: @Julia I right click and I see 'find in folder' but that's to search for all the files that contain a word. I don't want to find words, I just want to find files.

Comment: No right click, just a normal click.

Comment: @Julia is it possible for you to show me with a gif? Cause Im clicking on the workspace and folder and nothing happens.

Comment: Sure! [Is this better](https://ibb.co/kxprhn2)? (I just realized it would've been clearer if I enabeld Screencast Mode, but I really don't want to have to go back and redo the whole video unless I have to :))

Comment: @Julia Thanks, I had to log into another account to make that work but even that is limited I think see updated question --> This kinda works but when I do '.go' I only find 2 files. I know the hugo repo has way more than 2 go files. I think this would probably have to be an extension similar to todo tree if I wanted that output.

Comment: It is rather limited, indeed. :( it searches only expanded folders.

Comment: @Julia yea I would make an extension to make this happen if it didn't take me 300 lines of javascript code to do what I can do in vim with  a 2 line vimscript function lol.

Comment: that is because somebody else has written the 300 lines of vim-script/C++

Comment: @rioV8 Yea I agree. It is nice that someone took the time to make it easier for developers to create plugins easily in vim. The vimscript language is not perfect but it gets the job done.